# VoltDB cluster eating all RAM

Tags: voltdb

I've setup a 3 machine VoltDB cluster with more or less default settings. However there seems to be a constant problem with voltdb eating up all of the RAM heap and not freeing it. The heap size is recommended 2GB.

Things that I think might be bad in my setup:

- I've set 1 min async snapshots
- Most of my queries are AdHoc

Event though it might not be ideal, I don't think it should lead to a problem where memory doesn't get freed.

I've setup my machines accordingly to [2.3. Configure Memory Management](https://docs.voltdb.com/AdminGuide/adminmemmgt.php).

On [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXH2e.png) you can see sudden drops in memory usage. These are server shutdowns.

[Heap filling warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiKR3.png)

[DB Monitor, current state of leader server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R9F4.png)

I would also like to note that this server is not heavily loaded.

Sadly, I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem. Most of the advice were targeted on fixing problems with optimizing memory use or decreasing the amount of memory allocated to voltdb. No one seems to have this memory leak lookalike.

Answer (score 0):

one thing that breaks voltdb performance more than anything is the ad-hoc queries.
I relies on stored procedures and precompiled query plans to work at high volume high speeds.
if you provide with more information about what you are trying to achieve I may be able to assist more.

Comment: This is more of a comment then a answer